# how can I prevent end users from running scripts in their own browser console

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a button click function. Using that button click, i will send ajax request to server. Here i have an issue with browser console. If i write setinterval and trigger click on browser console, button is triggering continuously and sending request to server.

On browser console if i write like below. It continuously triggering button and in that click function continuously sending ajax calls to server.

```
setInterval(function(){$(".button").trigger("click")}, 1000)
```

how can I prevent others from doing that in their own browser console?

Comment: Please add the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @muralikrishna, It's doing what you are telling it to. The `setInterval` function will call the call your provide every [provided] milliseconds (1000 in your case). If you could tell what you want to achieve, it would be easier to help out. How do you wish to call `trigger`?

Comment: (The question here appears to be, how can I prevent _others_ from doing that in their own browser console, flooding my site with unwanted requests.)

Comment: yes,exactly my question should be like that only.@CBroe

Comment: you can use content security policy. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy